# How to add tags to an fxml file through controller in javafx?

Tags: javafx, fxml

```
 <AnchorPane>
<TreeView fx:id="locationTreeView"  focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="449.0"      prefWidth="725.0" style="#tree&#10;{&#10;-fx-border-style:solid;&#10;-fx-border-width:1px;&#10;-fx-border-color:#ffffff;&#10;}"/>
```

In the above fxml code I want to add one more `<TreeView>` but through the controller. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to:

1. Give a `fx:id` to the `AnchorPane`:

   ```
   <AnchorPane fx:id="theAnchorPane">
   ```
2. Add the corresponding field in the controller:

   ```
   @FXML private AnchorPane theAnchorPane;
   ```

From the code that performs the addition you have to:

1. Create the new `TreeView` however you like:

   ```
   TreeView newTreeView = ...;
   ```
2. Add it to the childen of the `AnchorPane`, possibly with some constraints:

   ```
   theAnchorPane.getChildren().add(newTreeView);
   AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(newTreeView, ...); // etc
   ```